# Получение HTML кода после загрузки JS скриптов

Tags: c#, html

Нужно получить исходный код страницы, в котором есть определенные элементы ( находятся в отдельной шапке на странице ). Эта шапка появляется только после того, как проходит загрузка определенных JS скриптов, если скрипты не грузятся - соответственно и элементов данных нет.

Как можно реализовать получение кода, без использования к примеру, `webBrowser`?

Сам же использую библиотеки `xNet` для подключения и получения кода, а так же `Html Agility Pack` для парсинга содержимого.

Comment: Разберитесь в работе js скриптов. Возможно ваши данные подгружаются отдельным ajax запросом. Вы сможете повторить его xNet и сгенерировать необходимый html код с помощью HAP

Answer (score 0):

В HTML как и в ЯП выполнение кода идет по очереди сверху вниз. То есть вам нужно сначала дать таги (подгрузить ваши `js` файлы) `<script src="YOUR_NEED_SCRIPT.js"></script>` ну а потом соответственно вашу "шапку". И конечно же не забудьте убрать `async defer`, чтобы он не грузился асинхронно.

Так же вы можете загузить ваш HTML динамически после загрузки необходимых скриптов.

```
//With jQuery
//this place you load need scripts,
//after add html to document

var html = "YOUR_HTML";
$("div.head_container").append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

1. Вывел в `textbox` весь полученный код ( грешил на то, что код попросту не успевает загрузиться полностью ).
2. Разобрал полученный код
3. Прошелся по всем путям, до моего элемента.
4. Обнаружил что полученный `Xpath` из `Google Chrome` был не совсем правильный.
5. Убрав лишний `/tbody` получил нужное мне значение элемента без ошибок.

Спасибо!